# How to install an specific version of Docker on Amazon Linux AMI

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, docker

As the Docker team advances with new features frequently, the Amazon Linux AMI repo (amzn-updates) Docker package is not always up to date, hence some latest features are not immediately available (e.g. when installing Docker with `sudo yum install -y docker`).

How can I install an specific version of Docker on Amazon Linux AMI?
Are there pros/cons if Installing it with amazon package manager vs manually?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

As Docker Introduces two different flavors (CE and EE) the best and easy way of installing Docker on any system. please run the below command and you do not have to do any thing.

`wget -qO- https://get.docker.com/ | sh`

if you want to install a specific version of a docker, you can run below command to find what all version of docker is present.

`apt-cache madison docker-ce #(for ubuntu)
yum list docker-ce.x86_64  --showduplicates | sort -r #(for centos)`

then select the proper version and place it in below command.

`wget -qO- https://get.docker.com/ | sed 's/docker-ce/docker-ce=<DOCKER_VERSION/' | sh`

Comment: ERROR: Unsupported distribution 'amzn'